# Sometimes my monitors stop working an my Dell Precision with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, dell, display-resolution, hdmi

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 running on a Dell Precision, to which I have connected two Samsung monitors `S27H850QFU` connected through a HDMI to USB-C converter. It's not exactly a HDMI to USB-C converter since has 3 inputs (HDMI, USB-C and USB 3.0) and one output (USB-C) which I connect to the laptop.

Just to clarify, I have two of these 'hubs/converters' connected to two of my laptop's USB-C ports.

The problem is that sometime, when I boot, I find a combination of the following problems with the monitors:

- One of them doesn't come up.
- One of them doesn't show all the resolutions that should be available. For instance, I see 1920x1080 as the maximum resolution  while the maximum is 2560x1440.
- Sometimes I just turn off one of the monitors, but I still have the problem above.
- Sometimes the problem gets fixed by unplugging/plugging one or both monitors. Sometimes it doesn't.
- Sometimes I have one monitor plugged and working fine and, when connecting the second one, one or more of the above problems happen.

Generally, I need to reboot one or more times until the above gets fixed (that is, I have (at least) one monitor with the maximum resolution available)

I'm using the `Intel Corporation UHD Graphics` driver:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 097e
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

I have listed the available resolutions when the problem is happening:

```
> xrandr

Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1680 x 1050, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP-1-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1200     59.95 +  59.88    47.96  
   1920x1080     60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   [...]
DP-1-1 connected primary 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88* 
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1-2 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   2560x1440     59.95 +
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

DP-1-1 and DP-1-2 are the monitos, Screen 0 is the laptop one. I don't know what DP-1-3 is.

I have tried as well to set the resolutions through the terminal:

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 # script name: monitors.sh
  3 xrandr --output DP-1-1   --mode 2560x1440 --right-of   DP-1-2
  4 xrandr --output DP-1-2   --mode 2560x1440 --left-of  DP-1-1
```

and, when executing it, I get:

```
bash ./monitors.sh 
xrandr: cannot find mode 2560x1440
```

I have observed that, after trying to plug in the second monitor and having the error, and recovering by unplugging it, I see 'ghost' devices in `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP-1-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
[...]
DP-1-1
[...]
DP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I have tried to remove DP-1-2 and DP-1-3 to see if that is the problem, but neither `xrandr --rmmode` nor `xrandr --delmode` can do it.

Comment: Sounds like the ports have border line power to run the 2 monitors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have fixed the problem but attaching both monitors to a dock station through HDMI and mini DisplayPort respectively, and authorizing the dock station from Ubuntu. I imagine my previous adapters weren't very good.

Comment: So, nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: It has all to do with Ubuntu. If I use two HDMIs in either Mac or Windows, all works without no problem (no way this happens on Ubuntu). In addition, both OS' perfectly remember the monitor configuration, so I don't need to re config it all the time.

Comment: *I imagine my previous adapters weren't very good.* enough said.

Comment: I repeat, I have tried both adapters on a Mac with a dockstation and they work....

Comment: And I repeat: Unless you test the same peripherals in the same computer with a different OS and confirm they work as expected, the OS is unrelated, immaterial and irrelevant. That the same peripherals work in a totally different computer is also unrelated, immaterial and irrelevant. Troubleshooting 101. End of story.